# Single-user PHP OAuth request using PECL

Tags: php, oauth, pecl, pecl-oauth, oauth-php

I'm trying to implement an api (The Noun Project), and they've provided this example: https://gist.github.com/hirobert/710f2e22ed803dc34cc0

I'd love to implement this using the [OAuth PECL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php)
I'm unfortunately getting stuck, since it doesn't follow a conventional oauth flow.

I don't need an account's authorization. Rather, I just need to use my key/secret to make calls.

This is where I'm getting stuck:

```
$oauth = new OAuth(
    $key,
    $secret,
    OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,
    OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI
);
$oauth->enableDebug();
$oauth->fetch(
    $url,
    array(),
    OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET
);
```

Am I able to use the OAuth PECL library, or should I look elsewhere?
Best would be if anyone knows of any examples of this kind of flow, using PECL OAuth; I'm sure I could apply their approach to my case